# Extract screenshot or picture of portion of PDF using VBA or VB and Adobe SDK

Tags: vb.net, excel, acrobat, acrobat-sdk, vba

I am currently using an excel macro (although I will switch to VB.NET if necessary) to loop through all of the text in a PDF and populate an array with certain portions of the text in the PDF (via the Adobe SDK and getPageNthWord). This part is working just fine, but now what I want goes a step further.

There are certain portions of the PDF where just grabbing the text isn't giving the full picture, and I'd like to see what more I can get. This is exactly the screenshot or snippet I am trying to get:

[image]

So, I know that I could use getPageNthWordQuads to find the coordinates for the words "Compliance Warning" and I could figure out a way to find the bottom right of the screen as well, but my problem starts there. After I get those coordinates what would I do with them? Can I zoom in the PDF to only see that portion and then take a screenshot? I already have the code for a screenshot of the activewindow, but I don't know how to scroll or zoom on a PDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. A fresh approach would be welcome as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a number of approaches that would work - I don't know enough about your environment / constraints to know for sure which would work best. I'm assuming you are talking to Acrobat through OLE here.

1) You can open a window, get its AVPageView and ask it to zoom and move to where you want it to do your thing.

2) You can open a PDF document in one of your own windows using OpenInWindowEx and then grab the contents of that window (the advantage being that this window could be off screen).

3) You can use the DrawEx method (in AcroExch.PDPage) to render a specific portion of a page into your own window and then process that.

Comment: hmm, could you supply any sample code for this? (VB or VBA?) or know of a place you could link me to?

Comment: No samples I'm afraid - I do my work on Mac these days. But the Adobe Acrobat SDK contains all of the documentation (and might actually have samples when you download the Windows SDK): http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html